# Delphi 2010 Json Parsing

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, parsing, delphi-2010

How to parse this line here on delphi 2010:

```
{"list": [{"id": "107","name": "John","fname": "Doe"},
          {"id": "108","name": "Alex","fname": "Man"}],
    "success": 1,
    "count": "2"}
```

Comment: To parse JSON, use a JSON parser.

Comment: I tried to remake various examples of parsing , but failed =(

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using? Do you know what a JSON parser is? It's fine if your answer is no. Then we can tell you and make your life easier.

Comment: Now turned to remake one example , it works , but it seems he did not correct

Answer (score -1):

```
procedure parse_3;
var
  txt: PAnsiChar;
  js: TJSONArray;
  lat: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  try
    txt :=
      '{"list": [{"id": "107","name": "John","fname": "Doe"},{"id": "108","name": "Alex","fname": "Man"}],"success": 1, "count": "2"}';

    js := ParseJSON(txt);
  except
  end;
  if Assigned(js) and (js is TJSONObject) then
  begin
    if js.field['success'].value = 1 then
    begin
       for i := 0 to StrToInt(js.field['count'].value) - 1 do
       begin

        showmessage(js.field['list'].child[i].field['id'].value +' | '+js.field['list'].child[i].field['name'].value +' | '+js.field['list'].child[i].field['fname'].value);
       end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If an exception is raised then you swallow it and `js` is not initialized. All subsequent use of `js` is therefore invalid. -1